# discord.py: importing function from main.py causes asyncio.run() error

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, task

I have a `discord.py` project that has a main.py file that runs `client.run(discord_token)` and also has two other `async` functions called `get_mongo()` and `dump_mongo()`. I have another file called /Web_Interaction/loopty_loop.py that needs to import these two functions. I call these two functions inside of a looped function in loopty_loop.py.

```
from discord.ext import tasks
import asyncio

@tasks.loop(time=times)
async def curate(client, channel, mongo_client):
    print('curating...')
    from main import get_mongo, dump_mongo

    ...
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andy/CE-Assistant/main.py", line 1433, in on_ready
    await master_loop.start(client, mongo_client)
  File "/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 264, in _loop
    raise exc
  File "/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 239, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andy/CE-Assistant/Web_Interaction/loopty_loop.py", line 102, in master_loop
    await curate(correct_channel, mongo_client)
  File "/home/andy/CE-Assistant/Web_Interaction/loopty_loop.py", line 119, in curate
    from main import get_mongo, dump_mongo
  File "/home/andy/CE-Assistant/main.py", line 1437, in <module>
    client.run(discord_token)
  File "/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

If I move `from main import get_mongo, dump_mongo` to outside of my function, I get a circular import error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: fixed the problem by moving both of the functions to a new file called `mongo_silly.py`, but I would love to know how to avoid this in the future

Comment: Why do you need to run the bot in your cog/utility file? You can just remove the repeated `.run`/`.start` there.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain 2 important things in Python:

#### 1. What happens at an import?

The `import` statement has a bit more functionality as it might seems. When you import something, Python evaluates the whole file/module. This means that whatever code you put into your second python file, when  you import it, it‘ll be executed

Your issue is that importing your main.py is trying to run your bot, which leads directly to:

#### 2. How can we circumvent this?

Changing code to not execute on import is fairly simple and forward.
Any code that you don‘t want to be executed when it‘s imported should make use of the most used Python if-statement: `if __name__ == “__main__“:`

#### How does it work?

Python assignes each file the `__name__` variable, which holds the name under which the file is executed. While modules and files get their name assigned, the main script gets `__main__` assigned, because it‘s the file running the program

Simply putting your `bot.run()` into this if-statement will exclude it from executing